# Librarys in TikZJax

Tags: tikz-pgf, html, svg, mathjax

https://tikzjax.com/

https://tikzjax-demo.glitch.me/

*Is it possible to use librarys in TikZJax?*

I testet

```
\tikzset{
    background rectangle/.style={fill=red, rounded corners}, 
    show background rectangle,
    }
```

without success in the 2nd link.

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]

\tikzset{
background rectangle/.style={fill=red, rounded corners}, 
show background rectangle,
}
\draw (0,0) circle (1in);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: While it is not recommended (with usual LaTeX), you could place the `\usetikzlibrary` inside the `tikzpicture`. However, doing `\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\tikzset{execute at end picture={\pgfonlayer{background} \fill[red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current  bounding box.north east);\endpgfonlayer}}` breaks after adding the `pgfonlayer` environment while it works with pfdLaTeX. Have you tried other libraries?

Comment: Related issue [#2](https://github.com/kisonecat/tikzjax/issues/2#issuecomment-1113795879), linked to someone trying to fork it and allow for more packages/libraries to be added. Further down someone talks about how to edit a json to allow adding packages.

Comment: I'm asking about libraries in general. I just had to think out one example.

Comment: There is a log available via browser tools. Even if I do `\end{tikzpicture}\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}\begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle]` it complains about unknown key `/tikz/show background rectangle` despite seemingly loading the library file. It seems the answer to your question is simply “No”, at least out of the box (see the mentioned discussion above). With my first example, the error is `Package pgf Error: Sorry, the requested layer 'background' could not be found`. So, it just doesn't “executes”/compile the library's code properly.

Comment: x-site duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/77758813/2777074

Answer (score 2):

[drgrice1's fork](https://github.com/drgrice1/tikzjax/tree/ww-modifications) may do this, but it's hard to build (I have never succeeded). [benrbray's fork](https://github.com/benrbray/tikzjax) provides a Dockerfile for build and I followed the Dockerfile for a build guide and succeeded.

You can try to put your code like this (no need to add `\documentclass{standalone}` and `\usepackage{tikz}`):

```latex
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]

\tikzset{
background rectangle/.style={fill=red, rounded corners}, 
show background rectangle,
}
\draw (0,0) circle (1in);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

into my live demo: https://bill-ion.github.io/tikzjax-live/ , and the result will automatically appear in the box on the right.